# set_layout settings in Sublime Text 3

Tags: configuration, sublimetext3

I just changed my OS from W10 to a Linux distro. I installed Sublime Text 3 and started to configure everything as I had in my other OS so I could start programming. Right now I am trying to include some custom layouts but I'm having a problem.

This is a layout I wanted to make:

[image: Sample Layout]

So I wrote this:

```
{
    "keys": ["alt+shift+5"],
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.33, 0.5, 0.66, 1.0],
        "cells": [
            [0, 0, 2, 1],
            [2, 0, 4, 1],
            [0, 1, 1, 2],
            [1, 1, 3, 2],
            [3, 1, 4, 2]
        ]
    }
}
```

But this is not working for me right now.

Comment: What do you mean by not working; the key binding doesn't do anything? If so, do other custom key bindings work?

Comment: @OdatNurd i dont mean that, the thing is that the layout isnt working, the key i stablished is just for setting that layout but the layout doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to apply that layout generates an error message in the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`):

```
invalid cell: (2,0 4,1)
```

That sort of catches me by surprise because generally the `set_layout` command takes what you give it without doing any error checking, which can get you into sticky situations like weird rendering errors or putting panes outside of the visible area of the window.

In any case, modifying the layout to something like the following solves the problem, which re-orders the cell layouts.

```
{
   "cols":[0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
   "rows":[0.0, 0.33, 0.5, 0.67, 1.0 ,
   "cells":[
      [0, 0, 1, 2],
      [1, 0, 2, 1],
      [0, 2, 1, 4],
      [1, 1, 2, 3],
      [1, 3, 2, 4]
   ]
}
```